# Should I create a table for only few rows?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

Good day everyone, I didn't find any answer to my question on the net. I have some tables in my db that contain only few rows and will not have more. For example:

```
1- status_orders (payed, declined, shipped, delivered, returned, ...)

2- payment_means (card, cheque, bank transfer, paypal, ...)
```

knowing that i have a multilingual website, i have to create other tables that contain translations which means more JOINS...

Do you think I should keep doing it like this or simply use a PHP array and store its key in the database or maybe there is another better way to deal with this!!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a good thing to have those values stored in the database.

If another system wants to query data from your database, it will be possible for that system to know what these statuses are. That won't be the case if these statuses are encapsulated in your code.

However, for the translations, I see 3 options:

- Have a table where you stored them (will cause more join as you just mentioned)
- Have a field for each value of your table and store the translations into a JSON array format

  > [{language: "fr", value: "Description du type"}, {language: "en",
  >   value: "Description type"}]
- Store the translations of your types in your PHP code

Comment: Thanks Elferone for your reply. Actually we dont work with any external system that may request our database for these fields!
For translation, I for now use 2 tables (status_orders & status_orders_translations) but looking to optimise this. But in term of db design, isn't better to use tables only for growing data?

Comment: I don't see any problem using tables for storing these type of data. As for your translation tables, you could do a generic one. In that case, you won't need to create a table each time you add an entity to your model. Just a suggestion!

Comment: There is absolutely no problem, but I just heard that if a table contains data that never grow, it's better to do it differently because because we may have useless JOINS that may slow down the query, and that's why I'm posting about it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are times when it makes sense to have a table with *one* row with *one* column.  So, odd-sized tables are sometimes the "right thing to use".

PHP is a tempting alternative, but how would you "persist" the information?  And if you can `JOIN` this tiny table to something else, that might be simpler than mixing metaphors (SQL and PHP).

Think of the databases as the "source of truth" for all the data.  Think of your client (PHP) as the "business logic engine" that manipulates that data *and* "presents" it (via a webpage, for example).

Comment: Thanks Rick for your reply. What do you mean with "persist the information"? Well, in a query with around 8 tables, I have run some tests and noticed that JOIN with 1 or 2 more tables increases the query time by about 0.2s. More over, the tables in talking about will require an additional table for each for translations :/

Comment: "Persist" means to save the data somewhere so that it will be remembered the next time the program is run.  If nothing needs to be save, the the point is moot.  The `JOIN` should not add that much; let's see the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; perhaps there is an index missing - especially a 'composite' index.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation ;) nothing has to be saved as these values won't change, or maybe I'll ne to add a new order status but it won't happen more then once a year... :) I for now didn't finish the db design, I'll update my initial post when I get to it ;)

Comment: Hey, I'll finally stick with the data saved in the db as you recommended :)
I'll have one new question please:

an order can have multiple tracking numbers, so i created a new table (orders_trackings) with 2 columns (order_id, tracking number), so should I create another column autoincrement which will be the PK? or set order_id & tracking number as PK?

Thanks a lot

Comment: That sort of sounds like a "1:many" relationship, which only needs an id of the "1" table in the "many" table.  For "many:many", an auto_inc is a waste.  See my advice here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table  It says 'yes' to that composite PK.

Comment: OK, so if I understand well, i should use a composite PK on these 2 fields even if I never gonna use tracking_number in a WHERE condition?
And talking about "WHERE", i read somewhere that I must always index columns used in WHERE and ORDER BY, is that true or is there any exceptions to that?

Comment: @Websphere - there are too many exceptions to say 'even if' / 'must' / 'always'.  For example, a 1-row table won't bother using an index, regardless of what else is going on.  See my [_cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for some answers.  Another example:  `WHERE 1=1` (and nothing else) can't use any index.  Except for a "covering" index.  Etc, etc.

Comment: and...  `WHERE x=1 ORDER BY y` would love `INDEX(x,y)`.  But that index is less helpful for `WHERE x>1 ORDER BY y`, in which case `INDEX(x), INDEX(y)` might be the best choice -- the Optimizer will pick one and ignore the other.  `ORDER BY DATE(dt) = '2017-05-30'` can't use `INDEX(dt)` because `dt` is hiding in a function (`DATE`).  Etc, etc.